# How can I figure out where a project is told to link a particular library in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I've got a Visual Studio project.  It's fairly simple, and it works.  However, we're in the process of porting our code to 64-bit.  I've got this simple project compiling, but it fails to link:

```
fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
```

That tells me it's trying to link the wrong version of the library.  It should be linking the 64-bit library, but it's trying to link the 32-bit library.  That's obviously wrong.

My problem is that I cannot figure out where my project is deciding to link that library.  I've looked at:

- Project Properties, props files.  Nowhere is a lib name specified, although the lib path is specified.
- Project Properties -> Linker -> Command Line.  Not there either.
- I've looked through the header files for some kind of a `#pragma comment(lib, )`, but I cannot find any use of that.

Where else can I look?  Is there a way to have Visual Studio tell me how it is deciding to link in different libraries?

Not sure if it's relevant, but this is a small unit test project, using CppUnit.  It's linking `cppunit-vc100-MTd.lib` when it should be linking `cppunit-vc100-x64-MTd.lib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your projects property page, under Linker, General, set the project link progress reporting to whatever you need to display the libraries being hit. /VERBOSE or /VERBOSE:lib will likely do what you want.

Example output of what shows up in the Output window with /VERBOSE:lib

```
1>  Searching libraries
1>      Searching D:\winsdk\lib\kernel32.lib:
1>      Searching D:\winsdk\lib\user32.lib:
1>      Searching D:\winsdk\lib\gdi32.lib:
1>      Searching D:\winsdk\lib\winspool.lib:
1>      Searching D:\winsdk\lib\comdlg32.lib:
1>      Searching D:\winsdk\lib\advapi32.lib:
1>      Searching D:\winsdk\lib\shell32.lib:
1>      Searching D:\winsdk\lib\ole32.lib:
1>      Searching D:\winsdk\lib\oleaut32.lib:
1>      Searching D:\winsdk\lib\uuid.lib:
1>      Searching D:\winsdk\lib\odbc32.lib:
1>      Searching D:\winsdk\lib\odbccp32.lib:
```

etc..

Also, you may have a header file in your source tree that is bringing the file in via a

```
#pragma comment (lib, "cppunit-vc100-MTd.lib")
```

but that should be easy enough to search by Find In Files hitting your Include Path, which is one of the canned options in the Find in Files configuration.

Comment: /VERBOSE:lib shows a list of the libs being used, which gives me another way to confirm it's linking the wrong library.  But that doesn't help me figure out where it got that list from.  I'll try /VERBOSE (but that's a LOT of output to sift through).

Comment: @Tim now that I see the offending library, I'm pretty sure it *is* a #pragma comment, so hit up a full-text search of all .h/hpp/inl files in your include path for that lib name. I think you'll find it. (fingers crossed)

Comment: I searched my entire code base, and the entire cppunit include path, looking for `pragma.*comment.*lib`, but no luck there.

Comment: I can go to `Project Properties -> Linker -> Input` and make use of `Ignore Specific Default Libraries` and `Additional Dependencies` to force it to ignore the 32-bit lib and link the 64-bit lib.  But that just seems wrong.  It feels like there should be a better way, a way to tell it to link the right lib in the first place.

Comment: @Tim Searching just your code base likely won't find it; *theirs* will (their headers) so unless their headers are included in your projects source file tree (not likely, but I've seen stranger) searching even Entire Solution won't find it. cpp-unit takes zero time to download and setup.I'll try and do that if I get a break from my current task @ work.

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear, I ran `ack 'pragma.*comment.*lib'` from the commandline.  I ran that for my entire source base, and I also ran it for all the cppunit header files.

Comment: bah!  CppUnit does not use `pragma comment(lib,...)`, but apparently we have a custom include file which does use that.  So it was a pragma statement, but it was hiding outside the normal code base.

Comment: @Tim Excellent, because I was having one helluva time finding the platform-specific cppunit you're using. Very glad you found it, sir.